# automatically print out (char *) of ESP+x value in Watch of WinDbg

Tags: windbg

I use WinDbg with a soft breakpoint for RegOpenKeyExA

```
bp RegOpenKeyExA
```

Info:

```
int RegOpenKeyExA Lib advapi32.dll (int hKey , char * lpSubKey, int ulOptions, int samDesired, int phkResult)
```

now I want to show the pushed value behind the adress of the second argument (lpSubKey) (@esp+8) in the WinDbg-watch-window typecast as "char"!:

**Example:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsMC4.gif
[image: windbg watch-window]

```
esp = 0018f1b8
```

Stack:

```
0018f1b8 1d 8c 23 76 02 00 00 80 d8 f1 18 00 00 00 00 00 01 00  ..#v..............
0018f1ca 00 00 d4 f1 18 00 24 f3 18 00 00 00 00 00 53 4f 46 54  ......$.......SOFT
0018f1dc 57 41 52 45 5c 4d 69 63 72 6f 73 6f 66 74 5c 57 69 6e  WARE\Microsoft\Win
0018f1ee 64 6f 77 73 5c 43 75 72 72 65 6e 74 56 65 72 73 69 6f  dows\CurrentVersio
0018f200 6e 5c 53 68 65 6c 6c 43 6f 6d 70 61 74 69 62 69 6c 69  n\ShellCompatibili
0018f212 74 79 5c 4f 62 6a 65 63 74 73 5c 7b 35 36 46 44 46 33  ty\Objects\
```

esp + 8:

```
0018f1c0 d8 f1 18 00
```

**now I try to get** : &(esp + 8) = 0018f1d8 typcast as char

```
0018f1ea 5c 57 69 6e 64 6f 77 73 5c 43 75 72 72 65 6e 74 56 65  \Windows\CurrentVe
0018f1fc 72 73 69 6f 6e 5c 53 68 65 6c 6c 43 6f 6d 70 61 74 69  rsion\ShellCompati
```

**result  may be**:

*(esp + 8) |  0x0018f1ea "\Windows\CurrentVe..."   |  char *

Answer (score 4):

> (char**)(@esp+8)

And then open up the value.  My example uses wchar_t** because I was dealing with Unicode.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

The C++ evaluator supports pointer dereferencing, so you can do:

```
*((char**)(@esp+8))
```

And avoid having to expand the value. Note that you can play with C++ expressions (which the watch window uses) with ??:

```
0:000> ??(char**)(@esp+8)
char ** 0x001bd1b4
0:000> ??*(char**)(@esp+8)
char * 0x75c0f5f8
 "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\OLEAUT"
```